# Ran Out Of Input

Tags: python, error-handling, pickle

```
  import pickle 
def write(): 
  with open("STOCK.DAT","wb+") as F: 
    N=[] 
    for i in range(1,3): 
      a=input("ENTRY") 
      N.append([a,a]) 
    print(N) 
    pickle.dump(N,F) 
    a=pickle.load(F) 
    print(a) 
write()
```

i just want to print that nested list the binary file but its giving me ran out of input error

Can anyone help please

Output

```
ENTRY1
ENTRY2
[['1', '1'], ['2', '2']]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
EOFError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-772931e3e569> in <cell line: 30>()
     28       print(i)
     29     print(a)
---> 30 write()

<ipython-input-10-772931e3e569> in write()
     24     print(N)
     25     pickle.dump(N,F)
---> 26     a=pickle.load(F)
     27     for i in a:
     28       print(i)

EOFError: Ran out of input
```

Above is the error i am getting

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please edit the question and add the full error traceback message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
pickle.dump(N,F) 
a=pickle.load(F)
```

File objects contain an internal pointer that keeps track of where the next read/write will occur.

After calling `pickle.dump()`, the internal pointer is at the *end* of the data that was just written.

So when you call `pickle.load()` that pointer is still at the *end* of the file, so there's nothing to read.

You need to reset the file pointer back to the beginning.

One way to do that is to call `F.rewind()`.

Or you could divide the code into two separate `with open ...` blocks, one for writing and one for reading.

Comment: it worked, can you tell 

def write():
  with open("STOCK.DAT","wb+") as F:
    N=[]
    for i in range(1,3):
      a=input("ENTRY")
      N.append([a,a])
    print(N)
    pickle.dump(N,F)
write()
why this function is returning me the nested list

Comment: It returns a nested list because that is the actual content of the file.   You declared `N` to be a list, and then you appended `[a,a]` to it, which is a sub-list.

Comment: @PiyushBaweja You *should* accept and upvote an answer if it works for you. It's the minimum courtesy in SE sites.